# Android firebase auth synchronous sign in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When we want code to run after sign in to firebase, we use 
`addOnCompleteListener` like this:

```
void signInToFirebaseUsing(GoogleSignInAccount googleAccount) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleAccount.getIdToken(), null)
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener { ...
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    ...                     
                } else {
                    ...
                }
            }
}
```

However, firebase isn't the only service I want to sign in. I need a synchronous firebase sign in so I could handle multiple authentications like this (I use Kotlin with [AsyncAwait library](https://github.com/metalabdesign/AsyncAwait), but you get the idea):

```
private fun signInToAppUsing(googleAccount: GoogleSignInAccount) {
    async {
        try {
            await { signInToRealmUsing(googleAccount) }
            await { signInToFirebaseUsing(googleAccount) } // <- this won't work because firebase uses asynchronous listener
            // User is signed in all services
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Signing in some service crashed
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sign into the other services inside task.isSuccessful(). as far as I know, there is no syncrhonous firebase userfriendly API, (it's probably obfuscated)

Comment: @Linxy Yea, that's an option, but would lead to 1) pretty unreadable code mess. 2) violating Single responsibility principle, because this kind of chaining requires every method in the chain call the next one.
So, it is doable, but not something I want. Doug Stevenson found quite clean ways to achieve this, as soon as I implement it, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase API wasn't designed to expose blocking work synchronous, it exposes blocking work as a Task to be listened to.

So, you can manage your own objects to maintain a record of the state of all the async work you want to track for completion.  Then, when the last thing finishes, proceed with whatever logic you want.

As you know, Play services (and Firebase) provides [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) objects that let you listen for success or failure.  If you convert all your async work to trigger their own Task objects to completion using [TaskCompletionSource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/TaskCompletionSource), and collect all the Tasks you want to wait for, you can then listen to the result of the aggregate collection of Tasks with [Tasks.whenAll()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)).

The [fourth part](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-4.html) of my blog series about Tasks covers this.

Comment: My sample isn't doing blocking work synchronously, code inside `await` doesn't run on the main thread. I just wanted firebase login function _itself_ to be synchronous, so I could manage threading on my own and could basically group all exceptions (from Realm and Firebase), I wanted to separate just 2 states: authentication succeeded in all services or it failed (no matter why). I hope I clarified it a little bit. I'll take a look at the Tasks, it looks promising. Thanks

Comment: Gotcha.  Taking an async thing, then turning it into a sync thing *can* be done (see Tasks.await()), but it's almost always never the best win.  The best win involves taking sync things and turning them into async things, then "joining" the async things to completion, so the whole mess uses fewer threads and has greater concurrency.  When using Firebase, you're kind of asked to subscribe to the Task way of doing things.

Comment: seams reasonable. I would probably be happier if Firebase API provided synchronous login as well as asynchronous (like Realm does), because I would prefer my async/await solution to Tasks solution as it's more readable for me (even though it's not as effective).

Comment: A decision was made a long time ago for Firebase APIs to never expose blocking work synchronously and instead always expose blocking work as a Task to be listened to.  It's similar to the JavaScript Promise API, and whatever is given for iOS as well.

Answer (score 4):

It's late, but today I face with this problem and just want to share  with others. I look around on internet and found a fun solution.

Because I use [RxFirebase](https://github.com/nmoskalenko/RxFirebase) (This version is compatible with RxJava 1. If you use RxJava 2, let use [Rx2Firebase](https://github.com/FrangSierra/Rx2Firebase)) , so I have an easy way to solve this problem. Just one line of code:

```
FirebaseUser user = RxFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance(), credential
).toBlocking().value();
```

If you are using Kotlin coroutines, let use [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/src/Tasks.kt) extension and then:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential).await()
```

Of course, this task should be started on background thread.

Comment: well, I think this is a valid solution, even though it requires a separate dependency. Thanks for sharing this.